# Downloading pictures/Word documents using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, response, content-type, content-disposition

If I put the following code:

```
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=capitol.jpg")
    Response.WriteFile(MapPath("capitol.jpg"))
```

into Page_Load, I will get the dialog box to download the image.  But when I put the same code into a sub routine:

```
Private Sub downloadPic()
    MsgBox("Hello!")
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=capitol.jpg")
    Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("capitol.jpg"))
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

I get the MsgBox (just for testing) but I don't get the ability to download the image.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can't output to the page and also push the download content within a single request/response.

Anyway your code won't work properly with a `Response.Clear()` before assigning header and `WriteFile`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  When I comment out the Page_Load code and try only the code in the downloadPic() sub routine, it doesn't download.  Do you know any good links to help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comment.  The problem with my code was that I had the WriteFile code within an UpdatePanel.  That was my mistake!